# Nullable Boolean value not working in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have below lambda expression for select list of my model.

**Note**: `state` variable can be `True`, `False` or `NULL`.

```
var list = APPEntites.Submited_Files
                     .Where(r => r.Category == id.Trim() && r.approved == (bool?) state)
                     .OrderByDescending(r => r.Date_Created)
                     .ToList();
```

I have an issue with selecting. If I pass this `STATE` variable with `Null`, it will return 0 list items, but if I use `null`, it will return the rows correctly. I want to know the reason for this issue.

Note: this code was working perfectly before.

Comment: have you tried to see the sql generated ? problem might be because of nullable bool

Comment: seems like you try to convert bool state into bool? inside Linq To Entities, and that might be a problem - as EF might try to reflect that on result SQL query. Try to make that conversion outside the Linq query

Comment: my state variable is bool? type and i tried explicitly and implicitly conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = APPEntites.Submited_Files
                 .Where(r => r.Category == id.Trim() && r.approved == state)
                 .OrderByDescending(r => r.Date_Created)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: i don't want to use additional variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.
Restarting Visual studio solved the issue.Strange!!.